# Find the password for my device

Tags: pattern

Today (January 3rd) my password is **HD82N**.

On 07/01 (January 7th) my password should be **IS42Y**

On 12/01 (January 12th) my password should be **AA91A**

On 18/01 (January 18th) my password should be **RR31U**

On 24/02 (February 24th) my password should be **VD40A**

What was my password yesterday (January 2nd)?

Hint 1:

> Firstly, did you notice how I spell my name each day.

Hint 2:

> The days are numbered

Hint 3:

> The week begins with monday

Hint 4:

> I count and I reach the beginning but then I begin again from the beginning

Hint 5:

> Each day ends with a day

Hint 6:

> I look back at how many dates are left for the end

Comment: In what format is 12/01 (assuming it's relevant for the puzzle)? MM/DD or DD/MM? Additionally, if relevant, it might be worth adding the dates of "today" and "yesterday" for people looking at this post some time in the future.

Comment: @Lolgast DD/MM is the format, agreed let me update

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in the textual representation of the dates. If this alters the puzzle or is not relevant, or the dates are different due to timezone differences, feel free to revert/change my edit, although if it alters the nature of the puzzle you might want to add the wordplay tag.

Comment: The dates are right :) I don't know much about the tags here yet @Lolgast

Comment: You can have a look at the tags via one of the buttons on the top. While I don't think the wordplay is applicable (and I certainly do hope it's not), some beginning users might make a puzzle where the password is somehow based on the word "today" and "yesterday", rather than the specific dates. Such puzzles tend to be too broad and are generally not well received.

Comment: My puzzle is based on specific dates and not just today or yesterday @Lolgast

Comment: Excellent! Imho that's a much better base for a puzzle. I'd say that the pattern tag is fine then

Comment: Two data points might possibly be too little to reliably establish a pattern; after all, *any* answer can be obtained by using nothing more complicated than a second degree function. From the looks of it, the method used here is not going to be significantly simpler than a second degree function. So Ima guess "hunter2". :-)

Comment: @Bass I will add more data points

Comment: Is the process strictly based on the date.  If so then is there a point at which the process must start over again...?

Comment: @Drt yes I will add a hint for that

Comment: Are you sure your password for Jan 12 is right??

Comment: @Drt yes the password is right

Comment: You probably won't answer this....but...how many days does the process span before it repeats?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71138/discussion-between-mehravish-temkar-and-dr-t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first letter is the positional letter from

> MEHRAVIS  with the IS tagged in for Sunday

The second letter is the positional letter from

> the day of the week where Mondays are M, Wednesdays are D

The number for the dates is the number or days

> to the end of the month in reverse, 19 days left in the month is 91

The last letter is the positional letter from

> The month where January makes the last letter for Sunday Y

Going by that rule the password for January 2nd is:

> EU92A

And likewise the password for January 4th is

> RR72U

And to clinch the approach the password for January 6th is

> VD52R

Comment: Impressive :) and the position is determined by the day of the week. Monday - 1 .. Sunday - 7

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.

**The first two letters:**

> I don't know yet. But I suspect they are derived from the week day of the date.

**The number:**

> The origin of the number is of no importance; The number seems to be incrementing by 1 each day ($12 - 03 = 9 = 91 - 82$).
> So the number for January 2<sup>nd</sup> is **81**.

**The last letter:**

> The last letter is the letter from "January" at index $N$ (in a rotating way) where $N$ is the day:
>
> ```
> JANUARYJANUARYJANUARYJANUARYJANUARY....
>   ^ 3rd letter (N)
>            ^ 12th letter (A)
>  ^ 2nd letter (A)
> ```

**Conclusion:**

The password for January 2<sup>nd</sup> is:

> **??81A**

Comment: Nice try, you are right about the last letter. The index N is different though. Partially right about the first two letters. Nowhere close for the numbers.

Comment: Also, you are right about the repeating part of the words being used